# Why is my form directing to the OnPost method - multiple forms Razor Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have been following the below linked tutorial in setting up a Razor pages with multiple forms.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6PE4p4gUYQ

In this tutorial it identifies that, of two forms (Form A and Form B), Form B's post can be directed to a post method other than 'OnPost', by using the asp-page-handler attribute and directing it to a different method other than OnPost (e.g. asp-page-handler="OnPostUpdateUnits").

I have implemented this in my code through the following tag helper:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="OnPostUpdateUnits">
    <select asp-for="Units" asp-items="Model.UnitsSet"></select>    
    <br /><button type="submit">Update Units</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately using this form (i.e. clicking the Update Units button) does not lead to execution of the OnPostUpdateUnits method, but instead leads to execution of the OnPost() method.  Any help would be appreciated in identifying what is going wrong, and how to direct the above tag helper to the OnPostUpdateUnits method.

Comment: "states that this is 'optional'. Including or not including it shouldn't make a difference."  That's mean `asp-page-handler="OnPost"` is 'optional, when it  leads  to execution of the OnPost() method, not mean  "OnPost" prefix  is 'optional'.  When you  handle multiple forms Razor Pages , the value passed to the page-handler attribute is the name of the handler method without the OnPost prefix or Async suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the "OnPost" part when you specify the handler name

It is just

```
... asp-page-handler="UpdateUnits">
```

Comment: It looks like removing the "OnPost" prefix fixed the issue.  However, this is unexpected.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6PE4p4gUYQ (6:01) states that this is 'optional'.  Including or not including it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I suggest this very informative site: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods I learnead a lot of subtle quirks on the subject there.